# Why is my Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter Algorithm implementation producing duplicate permutations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, permutation

I have implemented the [Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) using JavaScript, this implementation only calculates all permutations for arrays of numbers.

When the size of the array is >= 4 the algorithm is producing duplicate results. I see why it produces the results, but I am not sure how to avoid this, as creating these duplicates satisfies the algorithms principles.

```
class Direction {
    constructor(dir) {
        if(dir === 'LEFT' || dir === 'RIGHT') {
            this.dir = dir
        }
    }
    setDir(dir) {
        if(dir === 'LEFT' || dir === 'RIGHT') {
            this.dir = dir
        }
    }
    switchDir() {
        switch(this.dir) {
            case 'LEFT':
                this.dir = 'RIGHT'
                break
            case 'RIGHT':
                this.dir = 'LEFT'
                break
        }
    }
}
var permute = function(nums) {
    if(nums.length === 1) return [nums]
    if(nums.length === 2) return [nums, [nums[1], nums[0]]]
    // I'm only worried about arrays up to length 6
    const facts = [1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720]
    const dirs = {}
    const max = Math.max(...nums)
    nums.forEach(v => {
        dirs[v] = new Direction('LEFT')
    })
    const res = []
    const move = (n) => {
        const i = nums.indexOf(n)
        const ele = dirs[n]
        switch(ele.dir) {
            case 'LEFT':
                [nums[i], nums[i - 1]] = [nums[i - 1], nums[i]]
                break
            case 'RIGHT':
                [nums[i], nums[i + 1]] = [nums[i + 1], nums[i]]
                break
        }
        if(n === max) {
            return
        }
        nums.forEach(v => {
            if(v > n) dirs[v].switchDir()
        })
    }
    // Number is said to mobile if it can move to its direction
    const isMobile = (n) => {
        const d = dirs[n].dir
        if(d === 'LEFT' && nums.indexOf(n) !== 0) {
            return true
        }
        if(d === 'RIGHT' && nums.indexOf(n) !== nums.length - 1) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    // Finding mobiles means finding the largest number and checking if it is mobile
    const findMobile = () => {
        // If not max then lets find the next largest mobile
        var num = Number.MIN_VALUE
        nums.forEach(v => {
            if(isMobile(v) && v > num) {
                num = v
            }
        })
        return num
    }
    // Loop through the max length factorial, included up to only 6 as req
    while(res.length < facts[nums.length - 1]) {
        const next = findMobile()
        move(next)
        res.push([...nums])
        console.log(res)
    }
    return res
};
```

**Test Cases:**

```
    Test 1:
    Input: [1,2,3]
    Result: [[1,3,2],[3,1,2],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[2,1,3],[1,2,3]], Passed
 
    Test 2:
    Input: [5,4,6,2]
    Result: [
  [ 5, 6, 4, 2 ], [ 6, 5, 4, 2 ],
  [ 5, 6, 4, 2 ], [ 5, 4, 6, 2 ],
  [ 5, 4, 2, 6 ], [ 4, 5, 2, 6 ],
  [ 4, 5, 6, 2 ], [ 4, 6, 5, 2 ],
  [ 6, 4, 5, 2 ], [ 6, 4, 2, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 2, 5 ], [ 4, 2, 6, 5 ],
  [ 4, 2, 5, 6 ], [ 4, 2, 6, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 2, 5 ], [ 6, 4, 2, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 2, 5 ], [ 4, 2, 6, 5 ],
  [ 4, 2, 5, 6 ], [ 4, 5, 2, 6 ],
  [ 4, 5, 6, 2 ], [ 4, 6, 5, 2 ],
  [ 6, 4, 5, 2 ], [ 6, 5, 4, 2 ]
], Failed
```

As shown in the results, the algorithm is producing duplicates, however as mentioned earlier, the steps between the duplicates satisfy the algorithm.

**My Understanding of the Algorithm:**

All elements start out facing right to left:

ie. <1<2<3<4

We find the next largest "mobile" number, in this case 4. Then we shift it towards its direction.

ie. <1<2<4<3

Repeat the process.

If a mobile number is moved that is less than another number, the larger number has its direction swapped.

**EDIT**
I have solved the problem, it involved in not checking the size of the mobile number and number to be swapped.

Comment: This is not perfect, but you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to have unique solutions.

Comment: Are you saying that for array length 4, it is producing 48 results (24 distinct), or 24 results (12 distinct).

Comment: If you can read Python code, I would show working implementation

Comment: Also note that initial array should be sorted - otherwise you need proper array of directions

Comment: @RBarryYoung It is producing 24 results, with a few duplicates.

Comment: @MBo I keep an array of directions, listed as 'dirs' in my code.

Comment: You fill `dirs[v] = new Direction('LEFT')` in the beginning but this array does not correspond to 5,4,6,2 order.

Comment: @MBo I see, so I should be sorting before hand to unsure all directions point left. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MBo Weirdly enough there is no difference in the results no matter the orientation of the array. This is particularly confusing.

Comment: So what do you think about looking at Python implementation? I don't know JS enough to reveal possible flaws in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare steps with this simple Python implementation ([ideone link to look at results](https://ideone.com/67U2us), order is similar to [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) ).

I don't see direction items swapping together with elements in your code

```
def SJTperms(a, dirs):
    n = len(a)
    id = -1
    for i in range(n):
        #   can check mobility           mobile                        largest mobile
        if (0<=i+dirs[i]<n)       and (a[i] > a[i+dirs[i]])     and ((id == -1) or (a[i] > a[id])):
            id = i

    if (id == -1):  #last permutation
        return False

    for i in range(n):
        if a[i] > a[id]:
            dirs[i] = - dirs[i]

    #swap elements AND their directions
    a[id], a[id + dirs[id]] = a[id + dirs[id]], a[id]
    t = dirs[id]
    dirs[id], dirs[id + t] = dirs[id + t], dirs[id]
    return True

a = [1,2,3,4]
d = [-1]*len(a)
cont = True
while cont:
    print(a)
    #print(d)
    cont = SJTperms(a, d)
```

Comment: I stored the directions in a map, rather than an array. The map uses the number as the key, and the direction of the number as the value. Do you think that is incorrect? Also, your solution makes sense to me, except for the ```d = [-1]*len(a)``` line. Can you explain?

Comment: This is array of n (-1)'s [-1,-1,-1,-1]

Comment: So you represent left with -1 and right with 1 I see.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So a[id + dirs[id]] shows item in arrow direction.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth to uncomment #print(d) in ideone, get step-by-step output with directions `[1, 4, 3, 2] [-1, 1, -1, -1]`, and compare with your array and map state at every stage

Comment: I updated the post to explain the issue. Finally got this solved. Thanks a lot for your help!